# can't access xml node PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a page in php where I have to parse an xml.
I have done this for example:

```
$hotelNodes = $xml_data->getElementsByTagName('Hotel');
   foreach($hotelNodes as $hotel){
      $supplementsNodes2 = $hotel->getElementsByTagName('BoardBase');
      foreach($supplementsNodes2 as $suppl2) {
         echo'<p>HERE</p>'; //not enter here
      }
   }
}
```

In this code I access to each hotel of my xml, and foreach hotel I would like to search the tag BoardBase but it doesn0t enter inside it.

This is my xml (**cutted of many parts!!!!!**)

```
<hotel desc="DESC" name="Hotel">
   <selctedsupplements>
        <boardbases>
            <boardbase bbpublishprice="0" bbprice="0" bbname="Colazione Continentale" bbid="1"></boardbase>
        </boardbases>
    </selctedsupplements>
    </occupancy></occupancies>
</hotel>
```

I have many nodes that doesn't have BoardBase but sometimes there is but not enter.
Is possible that this node isn't accessible?

This xml is received by a server with a SoapClient.

If I inspect the XML printed in firebug I can see the node with opacity like this:

[image]

I have also tried this:

```
$supplementsNodes2 = $hotel->getElementsByTagName('boardbase');
```

but without success

Comment: I'm sorry pal, without the proper info there is nothing we can do...btw you are kind of rude, there is people helping people here, so, don't be agressive with your comments.

Comment: not aggressive only think that before answer is a good way to try the code only this, I don't want to be rude and sorry if I have make this impression, so sorry  @RobertRozas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 issues I can see from the get-go: XML names are *case-sensitive*, hence:

```
$hotelNodes = $xml_data->getElementsByTagName('Hotel');
```

Can't work, because your xml node looks like:

```
<hotel desc="DESC" name="Hotel">
```

`hotel` => lower-case!
As you can see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-5DFED1F0):

> [...] names for such things as elements, while XML is explicitly case sensitive.

The official specs specify tag names as *case-sensitive*, so `getElementsByTagName('FOO')` won't return the same elements as `getElementsByTagName('foo')`...

Secondly, you seem to have some tag-soup going on:

```
</occupancy></occupancies>
<!-- tag names don't match, both are closing tags -->
```

This is just plain invalid markup, it should read either:

```
<occupancy></occupancy>
```

or

```
<occupancies></occupancies>
```

That would be the first 2 ports of call.
I've set up a quick codepad using this code, [which you can see here](http://codepad.org/hHJnxP0a):

```
$xml = '<hotel desc="DESC" name="Hotel">
    <selctedsupplements>
        <boardbases>
            <boardbase bbpublishprice="0" bbprice="0" bbname="Colazione Continentale" bbid="1"></boardbase>
        </boardbases>
    </selctedsupplements>
    <occupancy></occupancy>
</hotel>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$badList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Hotel');
$correctList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('hotel');
echo sprintf("%d",$badList->lenght),
    ' compared to ',
    $correctList->length, PHP_EOL;
```

The output was *"0 compared to 1"*, meaning that using a lower-case selector returned 1 element, the one with the upper-case H returned an empty list.

To get to the `boardbase` tags for each `hotel` tag, you just have to write this:

```
$hotels = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html');
foreach($hotels as $hotel)
{
    $supplementsNodes2 = $hotel->getElementsByTagName('boardbase');
    foreach($supplementsNodes2 as $node)
    {
        var_dump($node);//you _will_ get here now
    }
}
```

As you can see [**on this updated codepad**](http://codepad.org/dK0mmzR4).

Comment: Well.. I have specified that is a piec of xml, occupancy is a node closed isn0t that the problem, hotel lower case isn't a problem this works fine into my code, you haven't solved my problem about node boardbase, no help this

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: I've updated the codepad. The case-sensitivity _is_ an issue. `getElementsByTagName('Hotel')` is not invalid, so it won't error, it'll just return an _empty_ instance of `DOMNodeList`. That's why you're not getting to the inner loop... it's as simple as that.

Comment: I have find the problem, inside firebug is written boardbase, but the real node xml is Boardbase. I don't understand why firebug print i lowercase all nodes

Answer (score 2):

Alessandro, your XML is a mess (=un casino), you really need to get that straight. Elias' answer pointed out some very basic stuff to consider.

I built on the code pad Elias has been setting up, it is working perfectly with me:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$hotels = $dom->getElementsByTagName('hotel');
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    $bbs = $hotel->getElementsByTagName('boardbase');
    foreach ($bbs as $bb) echo $bb->getAttribute('bbname');
}
```

see http://codepad.org/I6oxkEOC

Comment: Well, I've updated my codepad, and linked to it, too, in my edit to my answer. It works perfecty fine there, too... I also added a link to the official W3C XML specs: names _are case-sensitive_. That was the issue here

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem absolutely.

Comment: yes the issue is case sensitive, the real problem is that firebug print xml node all lowercase and isn't the truth in this case boardbase is different than Boardbase